# Angular 5 autocomplete is not working on the first call

Tags: angular, autocomplete

I'm using [ng5-auto-complete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng5-auto-complete) library for autocomplete in angular 5.

When I type in a character, then an API call get the suggestions to be displayed and it is set to the array.

```
onChanges():void {
this.newPLApplication.get('pLApplicationDetails').get('applicantOccupationDetailsDTO').get('companyName')
  .valueChanges
  .subscribe(
    term => {
      if (term != '') {
        console.log('got output yo');
        this.nPLApplication.getCompanyListByLetters(term)
          .subscribe((value: any) => {
            if (value.data!=null)
              this.setList(value.data);    
          });
      }
   })
 }
```

setList function sets the list to be displayed in suggestions.

I want that whenever I type a single character, it get the results from the api and display them in the list. But the problem is that the list is not appearing for the first character. It works fine when more characters are typed.

For example: when I reload the page and type 'a', then it shows 'no records found'. And when I continue typing like 'aa' then it will show me suggestions from the api. Now when I press a backspace, the input again becomes 'a', this time the suggestions get displayed.

This is my code inside the html:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" 
    formControlName="companyName" 
    (blur)="onBlur($event)" 
    id="list" 
    [ng5-auto-complete]="list" 
    no-record-text="No Records Found!"  />
```

I have also tried adding debounce time, but it still works the same way.
How can I make this work on typing the first character?

More info:

```
getCompanyListByLetters(letters: string): Observable<any[]> {
return this.http.get(environment.prodURL + 'v2/company/search/' + letters, this.requestOptions)

  .map((response: Response) => {
    let responseObject = response.json();
    if (responseObject.status == "success" || responseObject.status == "failure") {
      return (
        responseObject.length != 0 ? responseObject as any[] : [{ "BookName": "No Record Found" } as any]
      );
    }
    else {
      throw new Error('Something went wrong ..!!');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is `console.log('got output yo');` being printed when you type that first `a`?

Comment: yes it's getiting printed...even the api results are getting printed

Comment: Sounds like we'll need to see `.getCompanyListByLetters(term)` as well then I think

Comment: added the function, the this function is working properly.